# SQL Server stored procedures, returning multiple value in Else statement inside CASE clause

Tags: stored-procedures, in-clause

I want to use a CASE and IN clause inside a where clause

- When User Status = 1, CASE should return 1
- When  User Status  = 2, CASE should return 2
- When  User Status  = 3, CASE should return 3
- When User.Status = NULL, it should show all the user with  status 1, 2 and 3

But the below query is throwing a syntax error.

QUERY:

```
SELECT *
FROM User
where isInternalUser = 0 and DeleteMark <> 1 and
User.Status IN 
(
   CASE @UserStatus          // case for UserStatus
       WHEN 0 THEN 0
       WHEN 1 THEN 1
       WHEN 2 THEN 2
       ELSE (0,1,2)           
    END                      
)
```

Could anyone help me out..

Thanks,
Aneesh

Comment: You cannot return a single int (0) from one branch in your `CASE`, and a whole list of ints from another.

Answer (score 1):

Try without the `CASE` statement, but checking whether `@UserStatus IS NULL` or not:

```
SELECT *
FROM User
WHERE isInternalUser = 0 AND DeleteMark <> 1 AND (
    (@UserStatus IS NOT NULL AND Status = @UserStatus)
    OR (@UserStatus IS NULL AND Status IN (0, 1, 2))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
User.Status IN 
(
    SELECT s FROM (
        SELECT 1 s union SELECT 2 s union SELECT 3 s
    ) a
    WHERE @UserStatus is null or @UserStatus = s
)
```

Comment: Thanks, But the syntax error is still there. Incorrect syntax near ',' in ELSE statement

Comment: @user1437112 I guess you can't do this using a case statement.  Please see my update for an alternate method.